# PDO not inputting form data into database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to input form data into the database. I'm using almost the same code as I did for my registration script, which works perfectly. I'm completely stumped at this point.

I have error reporting turned on for PHP and PDO, nothing is happening. When the form is sent, it appears to work (except without the confirmation messages appearing) but nothing is entered into the database.

I have two files, request.php (the form) and parseRequest.php (the backend to the form).

## request.php

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="username" id="usernameField" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Headlining Band/Artist</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="artist" id="artistField" placeholder="Artist">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="day" id="dateField" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Venue</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="venue" id="venueField" placeholder="Venue">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>City, State</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="cityField" placeholder="City, State">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php if(function_exists('_token')) echo _token(); ?>">
            <button type="submit" name="requestBtn" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
```

## parseRequest.php

```
<?php
include_once 'resource/Database.php';
include_once 'resource/utilities.php';
include_once 'resource/send-email.php';
// Processing the form

if(isset($_POST['requestBtn'], $_POST['token'])){
    if(validate_token($_POST['token'])) {
        //process form here
        $form_errors = "";

    // validation
    $required_fields = array('artist', 'day', 'venue', 'city');

    // check empty fieldset
    $form_errors = check_empty_fields($required_fields);

    // date check
    $fields_to_check_length = array('day' => 10);

    //call the function to check minimum required length and merge the return data into form_error array
    $form_errors = array_merge($form_errors, check_min_length($fields_to_check_length));

    // collect data
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $artist = $_POST['artist'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $venue = $_POST['venue'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
}

else if(empty($form_errors))
{
    // preparing and inputting data
    try
    {
  $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO requests(username, artist, day, venue, city)
VALUES (:username, :artist, :day, :venue, :city)";

  //use PDO prepared to sanitize data
  $statement = $db->prepare($sqlInsert);

  //add the data into the database
  $statement->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':artist' => $artist, ':day' => $day, ':venue' => $venue, ':city' => $city));

        // email confirmation

        $addresses = array($_SESSION['email'], 'codylkaczynski@gmail.com');

        //prepare email body
        $mail_body = '<html>
        <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                            line-height:1.8em;">
        <h2>Amped Sound Staff Portal: Request Received</h2>
        <p>Dear '.$username.'<br><br>
        Your request for the '.$artist.' show in '.$city.' on '.$date.' has been received!</p><br/>
        <p>We will let you know if your request has been approved or denied ASAP.</p><br/>
        <p>Thank you!</p><br/>
        <p><strong>&copy;2018 Amped Sound</strong></p>
        </body>
        </html>';

        $namejeff = explode(',', $addresses);

        foreach ($addresses as $address)
        {
            $mail->AddAddress($address);
            $mail->Subject = "Request Received!";
            $mail->Body = $mail_body;
        }

        //Error Handling for PHPMailer
        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            $result = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">swal(\"Error\",\" Email sending failed: $mail->ErrorInfo \",\"error\");</script>";
        }
        else
        {
        $result = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            swal({
            title: \"Request received!\",
            text: \"We have received your request! Please check your email for confirmation.\",
            type: 'success',
            confirmButtonText: \"Thank You!\" });
        </script>";
        }
    }

    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        $result = flashMessage("An error occurred: " .$ex->getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

I appreciate any help I can get. I've tried a bunch of solutions I found on StackOverflow already, to no avail.

Comment: Change `else if(empty($form_errors))` to a simple `if(empty($form_errors))`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I knew I was going to have to punch myself in the face when I realized what the problem is. Thank you.

Comment: :) You are welcome. Just make it a `face/palm`, hurts less, and we have all been there :)

Comment: Are you getting the post data in your parseRequest.php.

You have to confirm first of all to where this form is redirect in actual.

In the form tag action is blank??