# Pull specific data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Basically, I have a table called `requests`, in that table there's a column called `status`. By default, `status` is set to pending, but can also be set to approved or denied.

I'm trying to display the data from the rows that have status set to pending, but not display approved or denied ones.

How do I do this?

My PDO statement:

```
try{

    $statement = $db->query("SELECT * FROM requests");
    $requests = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}catch (PDOException $ex){
    $result = flashMessage("An error occurred: " .$ex->getMessage());
}
```

The page where the data is displayed:

```
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <?php if(isset($request['status'] === 'pending')): ?>
                        <th scope="row"><?= $request['id']; ?></th>
                        <td><?= $request['username']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $request['artist']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $request['day']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $request['venue']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $request['city']; ?></td>
                      <?php else: ?>
                      <? # do nothing ?>
                    <?php endif: ?>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
```

My current code has the page resulting in a 500 error.

Thank you!

Comment: With basic SQL: `SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status = 'pending'`

Comment: This is one of the most basic SQL operations, you need to read a tutorial.

Comment: _Additional Note_ `<td><?php echo $request['username']; ?></td>` is better than `<td><?= $request['username']; ?></td>` as short codes are not always turned on in PHP

Comment: To whom it may concern that removed my other comment. There was a reason for that and it relates to comments made on the OP's [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388977/pdo-not-inputting-form-data-into-database) where he suggested he deserved a punch in the face.

Comment: _Another small note:_ The addition of a WHERE clause does not explain an Apache 500 error

Comment: @DontPanic Why delete your answer, it seemed very sensible to me

Comment: If there is an error 500, what does your server's error log contain about this?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't want it to be read while I was correcting my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 500 error is caused by two problems, first:

```
endif:
```

Check [the PHP documentation for alternative control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) - it's supposed to be

```
endif;
```

---

Then, this:

```
<?php if(isset($request['status'] === 'pending')): ?>
```

is not how to limit your results to only those with "pending" status. `isset` only takes variables, and giving it an expression like `$request['status'] === 'pending'` is another parse error. `isset` only returns false for variables that aren't set or are set to `null`.

It doesn't matter though, because you should filter by status in your query instead. Just add a WHERE clause, and get rid of that check in the PHP code.

```
"SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status = 'pending'"
```

Comment: Ah, mistakes sorted +

Comment: Yeah, @RiggsFolly I knew something still didn't look right. I was thinking PHP used to not allow expressions in `isset` and then added that at some point, but I believe that was actually `var_dump` I was thinking of. Wait... wrong again. It was `empty` I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely are getting the error 500 because you're not terminating the if statement. You need a semi colon.

```
 <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <?php if(! empty($request['status']) && $request['status'] === 'pending')): ?>
                    <th scope="row"><?= $request['id']; ?></th>
                    <td><?= $request['username']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $request['artist']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $request['day']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $request['venue']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $request['city']; ?></td>
                  <?php else: ?>
                  <? # do nothing ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
```